# Script is failing to pass XMLTYPE argument to PLSQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a script that is supposed to open an xml file and read the contents and process it. The plsql procedure TEST_LOAD.BOB_LOAD has been created successfully.

TEST_LOAD.BOB_LOAD looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE BOB_LOAD(p_uuid IN varchar2,
      xml_in IN  xmltype,
      msg_status OUT varchar2,
      xml_out OUT xmltype);

END  BOB_LOAD;
/
```

The script below calls this procedure in the final line and seems to be the cause of the error. I am assuming that it is not recognising the variable x as XMLTYPE.

```
DECLARE
    xml_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    chars_read INTEGER;
    xml_clob CLOB;
    xamount INTEGER :=32767;
    char_buffer VARCHAR2(32767);
    x XMLType;
BEGIN
xml_file := utl_file.fopen('/export/hm/testpit/bob', 'test.xml', 'r', xamount);
   DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(xml_clob, true);
 LOOP
 BEGIN
 UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(xml_file, char_buffer);
    chars_read :=LENGTH(char_buffer);
   DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(xml_clob, chars_read, char_buffer);
   DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(xml_clob, 1, CHR(10));
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   EXIT;
   END;
   END LOOP;
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(xml_file);
  x := XMLType.createXML(xml_clob);
  TEST_LOAD.BOB_LOAD('9718fa05-9995-4f17-jk1k-763113b8f4a4', x );
 END;
 /
```

However when I run the script above I get an ORA-06550, PLS:00306 error saying:

```
ORA-06550: line 39, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'BOB_LOAD'
ORA-06550: line 39, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your procedure has 4 parameters. You call it with only 2. You need to call it with the out parameters as well.

Much easier way to read a file's contents into a CLOB:

```
function read_clob_from_file(p_directory    varchar2
                               ,p_filename varchar2) return clob is

      l_amt        number := dbms_lob.lobmaxsize;
      l_dst_loc    clob;
      l_dst_offset number := 1;
      l_lang_ctx   number := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;
      l_src_loc    bfile;
      l_src_offset number := 1;
      l_warning    number;
   begin

      l_src_loc := bfilename(p_directory, p_filename);
      dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_dst_loc, true);
      dbms_lob.fileopen(l_src_loc, dbms_lob.file_readonly);
      dbms_lob.loadclobfromfile(l_dst_loc
                               ,l_src_loc
                               ,l_amt
                               ,l_dst_offset
                               ,l_src_offset
                               ,dbms_lob.default_csid
                               ,l_lang_ctx
                               ,l_warning);
      dbms_lob.fileclose(l_src_loc);
      return l_dst_loc;
   end;
```